For what values of does the integral $x^pe^{-x}$ converge?
For  what values of p $\in R$ does the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^pe^{-x}\,dx$ converge?
I've tried splitting the integral into $ \int_{0}^{1} x^pe^{-x}\,dx$ + $ \int_{1}^{\infty} x^pe^{-x}\,dx$ and then
= $ \lim_{a\to0}\int_{a}^{1} x^pe^{-x}\,dx$ + $ \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{1}^{b} x^pe^{-x}\,dx$
Using limit comparison test with $g(x) = x^p$ therefore $f(x)/g(x) = e^{-x}$ so $ \lim_{a\to0} f(x)/g(x) = 1$ and $\int g(x)$ is convergent for $p<1$
and for  second integral $\int g(x)$ is convergent for $p<-1$

Your conclusions for both integrals are off. For the first integral, analyze the exponent $p$ more carefully. For the second integral, there is no value of $p$ that would ever make it diverge. In general, limit comparison is for series and is not a robust tool for integrals even though in this case it would lead you to the correct conclusion if it had been applied correctly.

Can you explain your comment re integral 1 further please. Are you suggesting I use a different comparison function?

Your comparison function for the first integral is fine, you just came to the wrong inequality. Think more carefully about the exponent.

is it p<-1 for the first integral and subsequently for the entire integral as 2nd integral converges for all p?

Gamma function
